# Nome do arquivo como atributo com R

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho 3000 arquivos txt, com informações de 5 postos de observação. Cada txt corresponde a uma data. Gostaria que quando eu lesse e juntasse os txts o nome do arquivo constasse na linha de cada posto. Estou usando o R.library(dplyr)

por enquanto só consegui fazer a junção dos txts:

```
lista <- list.files(pattern = "txt")

arquivos <- lapply(lista, function(x) read.table(x, header=FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = "\"",dec = ",", na.strings = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE))

dados <- do.call ("rbind",arquivos )
```

No final meus dados estão saindo organizados assim:

```
1 PSATFZA -26.00 -51.65 16.73

2 PSATJSG -25.78 -52.00 13.16

3 PSATSCX -25.53 -53.48 12.18

4 PSATSCL -25.49 -51.74 28.52

5 PSATUVT -26.23 -51.08 20.7

...
```

queria que no lugar do número da linha aparecesse o nome do arquivo da onde veio essa informação. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Não sei se quer `names(arquivos) <- lista`.

Answer (score 1):

Duas opções, usando `data.table` ou `tidyverse`. Como nomes de linhas precisam ser únicos, melhor incluir os nomes dos arquivos em uma coluna. Usei nomes diferentes para os objetos para maior clareza.

```
# Arquivos de exemplo
for(i in 1:3) write.table(mtcars[1:2, 1:4], paste0("arq", i, ".txt"),
                          col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")

nomes.arquivos <- list.files(pattern = "^arq..txt$")
```

### data.table

```
library(data.table)

lista.dados <- lapply(nomes.arquivos, fread)
# data.table::fread detecta automaticamente separador e presença de cabeçalho

names(lista.dados) <- nomes.arquivos

dados <- rbindlist(lista.dados, idcol = "arquivo")

dados
#>     arquivo V1 V2  V3  V4
#> 1: arq1.txt 21  6 160 110
#> 2: arq1.txt 21  6 160 110
#> 3: arq2.txt 21  6 160 110
#> 4: arq2.txt 21  6 160 110
#> 5: arq3.txt 21  6 160 110
#> 6: arq3.txt 21  6 160 110
```

### tidyverse

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

lista.dados <- lapply(nomes.arquivos, read.table, sep = "\t")

names(lista.dados) <- nomes.arquivos

dados <- map_df(lista.dados, as_tibble_col, .id = "arquivo")

dados
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   arquivo  value$V1   $V2   $V3   $V4
#>   <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 arq1.txt       21     6   160   110
#> 2 arq1.txt       21     6   160   110
#> 3 arq2.txt       21     6   160   110
#> 4 arq2.txt       21     6   160   110
#> 5 arq3.txt       21     6   160   110
#> 6 arq3.txt       21     6   160   110
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rio)
```

A função `import_list()` do pacote `rio()` traz, por padrão, uma coluna que indica de qual arquivo veio o dado.

Criei dois arquivos txt para utilizar como exemplo:

```
file.create("arquivo_A.txt")
file.create("arquivo_B.txt")
```

E os preenchi com alguns dados:

```
cat("1 PSATFZA -26.00 -51.65 16.73\n2 PSATJSG -25.78 -52.00 13.16\n3 PSATSCX -25.53 -53.48 12.18\n4 PSATSCL -25.49 -51.74 28.52\n5 PSATUVT -26.23 -51.08 20.7", 
file = "arquivo_A.txt")

cat("1 XXXXXXX -26.00 -51.65 16.73\n2 YYYYYYY -25.78 -52.00 13.16\n3 ZZZZZZZ -25.53 -53.48 12.18\n4 WWWWWWW -25.49 -51.74 28.52\n5 TTTTTTT -26.23 -51.08 20.7", 
    file = "arquivo_B.txt")
```

Usando a função `import_list()`:

```
import_list(dir(path = "DIRETORIO DE TRABALHO",
                  pattern = ".txt"), 
              rbind = T,
              setclass = "tibble")
```

Com a função `dir()` você:

- informa no argumento `path =`  o diretório onde os arquivos estão;
- e no argumento `pattern =`  o padrão dos arquivos, que neste caso é qualquer arquivo que contenha ".txt".

E na função `import_list()` você especifica que quer fazer o bind das linhas e, se preferir já define que tudo seja arrumado em uma tibble.

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
      V1 V2         V3    V4    V5 `_file`      
   <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
 1     1 PSATFZA -26   -51.6  16.7 arquivo_A.txt
 2     2 PSATJSG -25.8 -52    13.2 arquivo_A.txt
 3     3 PSATSCX -25.5 -53.5  12.2 arquivo_A.txt
 4     4 PSATSCL -25.5 -51.7  28.5 arquivo_A.txt
 5     5 PSATUVT -26.2 -51.1  20.7 arquivo_A.txt
 6     1 XXXXXXX -26   -51.6  16.7 arquivo_B.txt
 7     2 YYYYYYY -25.8 -52    13.2 arquivo_B.txt
 8     3 ZZZZZZZ -25.5 -53.5  12.2 arquivo_B.txt
 9     4 WWWWWWW -25.5 -51.7  28.5 arquivo_B.txt
10     5 TTTTTTT -26.2 -51.1  20.7 arquivo_B.txt
```

Observe que a própria função criou uma coluna chamada `_file` que indica o arquivo de origem do dado.